# groovy JsonSlurper assertion for random number, random alphanumeric and date

Tags: groovy, ready-api, jsonslurper

I am pretty new to service testing and Groovy. The following is my response,

```
{
    encodedDiscountId=1275479, 
    encodedGuid=gOHSkGzQEee4-AJiXJP2jg,
    expirationDate=2017-08-17 17:00:00
}
```

I need help for the following assertions:

1. I need to assert if the DiscountId value is all random numerical of 7 digit long.
2. I need to assert I am getting an alpha numeric in upper and lower case with "-"
3. I need to assert the expirationDate should be 30 days from the system date.

I tried the script assertion and keep getting this error.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText(response)
assert json.encodedDiscountId.size() == 7
assert json.encodedDiscountId.matches("[0-9]")
```

Error:

```
assert json.encodedDiscountId.matches("[0-9]") | | | | 1043947 false [encodedDiscountId:1043947, encodedGuid:l0wWcG2KEee4-AJiXJP2jg, expirationDate:2017-08-18 17:00:00]
```

Comment: Please post your code, output, and errors as text instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is only for a single character in the character class from 0-9. You need to assert that the entire string is numbers, something like `/^[0-9]+$`.

`^` matches the beginning of the line and `$` matches the end, and `[0-9]+` means at least 1 number. And since it looks like the `encodedDiscountId` is always 7 digits, you can include that in the regex as `^[0-9]{7}$`.

Since there is a `$` in the regex if you are using double quotes you need to escape it as `\$` (`"^[0-9]+\$"`) or use slashy strings (`/^[0-9]+$/`) or single quotes (`'^[0-9]+$'`).

Comment: thanks @doelleri for the response,  `assert json.encodedDiscountId.matches("^[0-9]{7}$")` and keep getting this error `startup failed: Script27.groovy: 9: illegal string body character after dollar sign; solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 9, column 38. assert json.encodedDiscountId.matches("^[0-9]{7}$") ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: illegal string body character after dollar sign; solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 9, column 38.`

Comment: @peter You need to use slashy strings or single quotes to prevent Groovy from thinking the `$` is to insert a variable into the GString, or escape it with a `\$` as the error says.

Comment: Thanks @doelleri, single quotes worked. my 1st assertion passed yay!